# Finding the equivalent resistance between $K$ and $L$.

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4G21p.png)

I want to find the equivalent resistance between $K$ and $L$. By the way, I assumed that $4+3+6 = 15$ and $2$ is parallel. So, we get $\frac {15}{2}$. However, that's wrong. Could you help?

Comment: I didn't get what your hint means.

Comment: :/ Still trying to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint : It is equivalent to ....

[image]

Comment: I've arrived at correct answer! thanks for your hint

Comment: Also why is 4 with 2 and 3 with 6?

Comment: Keep moving the node $L$ up and to the right and it will become clear that the $3$ and $6$ are in parallel.